# Different Qt framework versions in different plugins on osx

Tags: macos, qt, frameworks

I have a plugin using some Qt frameworks, like QtGui.framework and QtCore.framework. My plugin depends on version 5.7, and this version is embedded in my plugin's bundle.

It seems that another plugin is using an earlier version (5.5) of these frameworks, and causing a versioning conflict. I'm worried that my plugin is finding the other one (which is located more publicly in /Library/Application Support/...) and not the one I have in the bundle.

Two questions:

1. `otool -L my_plugin` says that QtGui.framework is loaded by
   @rpath/QtGui.framework, and the output of `otool -l my_plugin` has a command that gives `LC_RPATH` as `@loader_path/../Frameworks`. Why is it finding the other plugin's framework if `@loader_path` points to my plugin?
2. Is it even possible for two plugins to load separate Qt framework versions in the same process? This question is for Qt, but I think it applies to any MacOS framework in general. I don't want to prevent the other plugin from working; I just want to work independently.

Comment: As long as the plugins use binary-compatible versions of Qt, you should do everything you can to ensure that they load only one version of Qt. Things will break otherwise: Qt is only binary compatible at its external interface. Qt modules are not mutually binary compatible, and you'll experience lots of breakage when the same process will have different Qt versions linked in, while the objects are being exchanged between them. It's not supported at all. It'll be brittle, in the worst possible way.

Comment: I see. So then what's best practice here, in a plugin-oriented environment, where any number of plugins can use different versions of Qt?

Comment: As long as the plugins use binary-compatible Qt versions, you can force the plugins to link to the version of Qt linked to your application, and only to that version. This is Mac OS specific and requires additional code to accomplish.